# angular http Url call returns -1 as status

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('app')
        .controller('Main', function ($scope, $http)
        {                       
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:62355/Product/GetProductList/3'
            })
            .then(function successCallback(response)
            {
                alert('hi');
            }, function errorCallback(response)
            {
                alert(response.status); // Display -1
            });
        });
```

When I use above code to call Url in angularjs,response object status : -1
statusText ="". Same Url works perfect in browser.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

response status -1 means that the API is offline (CONNECTION_REFUSED)
since Angular 1.3.19 (before the status code was 0)
which means that the url you try to call does not exist (hence there is no server listening to this call)

what does your browser respond when you enter the url

http://localhost:62355/Product/GetProductList/3

and where is your application hosted? is it hosted on your local machine ?
because "localhost" may be a difficult url if the app is hosted somewhere.

Comment: using angular 1.5. Url works perfect in browser. Also I replaced it with public Url

Comment: is this hosted anywhere publicly ? if you tell me the public url i can test it, this bug sounds kinda weird

Answer (score 0):

When the request is timed-out or aborted, the response is an error with status -1.

Timeout or way to abort the request is specified by the below option.

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that
>   should abort the request when resolved.

document excerpt from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Please check if this is what is happening for you.