# Angular returns status code as -1 instead of 302

Tags: angularjs

Trying to call one service from angular using $http. Normally the service will return 200 status code. But if the session is our it will return status 302. This I can see in the developer console network tab also. But in code the status code coming as -1

Here is the code

```
function getData(reqUrl) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: reqUrl
                });
            }


function get******(serviceName, callback) {
                getData(DataClient.serverUrl + '/****/services/rest/Q******/*****/' + serviceName)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        if (res.status == -1) {// here we need to check with 302
                            //session out
                        } else {
                           // rest of the code
                        }
```

What could be the issue? Why angular is giving -1 instead of 302?

Comment: what about [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35290542/8495123)?

Comment: Maybe the service is down?

Answer (score 0):

redirection on `302 Found` is done by browser.

So in the handler you will always get response from location you've been redirected to.

Check [Prevent redirection of Xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest) and [AngularJS docs on $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage), also [spec for XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) still does not allow handle redirection by client code.